# Is it still a petition if just one person signs it?

Tags: word-usage

The definition of 'petition' is;

> A formal written request, typically one signed by many people, appealing to authority in respect of a particular cause. [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/petition)

But what if just one person writes an official letter to, let's say, to the court to complain. For instance, Jack is subject to police corruption and decides to go to court, he wants to give a letter of complaint. What is the name of this paper?

Comment: What country or jurisdiction? Not all countries use the same words for legal documents and processes.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Turkey it is

Comment: Why would you ask about the name of a Turkish legal document on a English-language site?

Comment: In English, a single person can petition. The word comes ultimately from the word for _beg_, and begging can easily be done by individuals. The modern sense of a group petition is a relic of Western voting systems.

Comment: In the U.S., and individual has the right to petition, granted in the Bill of Rights (first ten amendments). On can petition her or his congressional representative, for example. So in the U.S., it can be just one person, as well as having many signatures.

Answer (score 2):

There are several senses of the word "petition". One is "A formal request made to a government or organisation"  This request can, and often would, be in the form of a letter, and could be signed by one person.

A second meaning is "a collection of signatures (of people who support some cause)" A collection of one is a failed petition.

It can also mean a spoken prayer, in which case nobody signs anything!

A letter written to a court, or other body to make a complaint is a "letter" or a "complaint", or "letter of complaint". In the UK, courts don't have investigative functions, so the exact situation is different.  You would write a letter of complain to the Independent Office for Police Conduct (or better, ask your attorney to write the letter of complaint)